# Does Laravel 5.1 Oauth work on localhost?

Tags: oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I have tried to implement lucadegasperi's Oauth2 library in laravel. I have tried both the versions of the library and have also tried bshaffer's Oauth library.

At first i thought i might be doing something wrong, but after trying so many versions and following a couple of tutorials it turns out that there is something else wrong.

**By the way i using laravel on a xampp installation on windows, with a customized domain. Is it possible that Oauth just doesn't work on localhost?**

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"grant_type\" parameter."}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit, it was POSTMAN plugin that i was using to test the api. I just tried using the terminal and also tried phpstorms REST api client and it works.